# How to keep messages in channel with no subscriber in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following set-up in a Spring Integration 4.1 project:

- A chain subscribed to a publish-subscriber channel.
- A service bus that starts/stops the chain.

What happens when I stop the chain, is that the messages dissapear from the topic and I would like them to remain there until the chain is activated again (much like a JMS queue). How could I achieve this behaviour?

I have tried this approach but I get an error from the "back up channel" stating that it does not have any subscribers to process the message:

[image]

1 - The publish-subscriber channel

2 - The chain being stopped/started

3 - The control bus gateway

4 - I have added a bridge and a regular channel to act as a Queue

This is the error I get with this solution:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:107)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
... 30 more
```

So, the question is: How should I configure my channels so messages remain there until a subscriber is added again? Is it possible?

Comment: Well, this in embarrasing, but I think I just need to add a `queue` element to the channel declaration in order not to use the `DirectChannel` implementation (which needs indeed a consumer to be present when the message is sent...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct; just make the channel a `QueueChannel` (add a `<queue/>` child element) and add a poller to the chain.

Comment: Thanks Gary. One question: Why should I need to add a poller to the chain?

Comment: Because queue channels need a poller to pull messages - or you can declare a default poller at the top level,

Comment: OK. That implicit use is not very intuitive but, luckly enough, I already had one declare for an inbound adapter... :)

Comment: If the default poller was not present you would get an error during initialization saying that there is no poller and no default poller is provided.